# Are there linked lists in Ul++?

Tags: ide

Are there linked list in NTL or somewhere in Ultimate IDE? I guess there is not but correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Just about every compiler that reasonably conforms to the C++ standard provides a standard libary implementation, which includes linked lists.

You're looking for [`std::list`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(C%2B%2B)) (a doubly-linked list implementation in C++), which is located in the `<list>` header.

Example:

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers;

    numbers.push_back(1);
    numbers.push_back(2);
    numbers.push_back(3);
    numbers.push_back(4);
    numbers.push_back(5);

    for(std::list<int>::iterator i = numbers.begin();
        i != numbers.end(); ++i)
    {
        // Do something with each element.
        // Each element can be accessed by dereferencing i.
        // For example:
        int number = *i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Nitpick: The Ultimate++ IDE is simply a graphical front-end for a C++ compiler - the IDE has no bearing on the availability of libraries.

Comment: well, here is >>>U++ is a C++ cross-platform rapid application development framework focused on programmers productivity. It includes a set of >>libraries (GUI, SQL, etc..)<<<<<, and an integrated development environment.<<<
I changed the title it seemed to mislead you.

So it has libraries too..

Comment: Right, U++ is an application framework, which includes all those things. The IDE itself, however, is simply a graphical front-end for a C++ compiler to make developing U++ applications easier.